# How to run FastAPI application from Poetry?

Tags: python, fastapi, python-poetry, uvicorn

I have a fastapi project built by poetry. I want to run the application with a scripts section in pyproject.tom like below:

```bash
poetry run start
```

What is inside double quotes in the section?

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = ""
```

I tried to run the following script.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

def main():
    print("Hello World")
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True, workers=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It stops the application and just shows warning like this.

> WARNING:  You must pass the application as an import string to enable 'reload' or 'workers'.

Comment: you found an answer ?

Answer (score 55):

I found the solution to this problem. See below:

In `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "my_package.main:start"
```

In your `main.py` inside `my_package` folder.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

def start():
    """Launched with `poetry run start` at root level"""
    uvicorn.run("my_package.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

You will need to pass the module path (`module:function`) to the `start` script in `project.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
start = "app:main"
```

Now run the command below will call the `main` function in the `app` module:

```
$ poetry run start
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as the error message says, do

```py
uvicorn.run("app")
```

Note also using reload and workers is useless and will just use the reloader. These flags are mutually exclusive

Comment: You literally saved me 8 hours of work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> WARNING:  You must pass the application as an import string to enable
> 'reload' or 'workers'.

try using the same way to run a basic script i.e `file:variable`

> ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Import string "app" must be in
> format ":".

```
uvicorn.run("backend.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True, workers=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code works for me

```py
# main.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", workers=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you wants to run with the start, but this can be achieved using following way:

```
poetry run uvicorn main:app --reload
```

--reload if you are running in development mode and this will do the hot deployment